# Is this a typo or I have misunderstood the group action?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $G$ be an affine group over field $k$ and $V$ be an affine variety over field $k$ with compatible left $G$ action.(i.e. $G\times V\to V$ is an algebraic morphism. Denote $k[V]$ the ring of functions of $V$ over algebraically closed field $k$. Let $f\in k[V],g\in G$. Denote $f^g(x)=f(gx)$. Suppose $G$ acts on $V$ from left.(Then I would expect $G$ acts on $k[V]$ from right due to $Hom(V,k)$ is contravariant in first slot.)

Let $x,x'\in G$. Denote $U_x:f\to f^x$

"$U_{xx'}(f)(v)=f^{xx'}(v)=(f^{x'})^x(v)=(U_x\circ U_{x'})f(v)$."

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why above is correct? Consider $(f^{x'})^x(v)$. Denote $g(w)=f^{x'}(w)=f(x'w)$ by definition. Now $(f^{x'})^x(v)=g^x(v)=g(xv)$ which amounts to evaluate $w=xv$. Then I get $g(xv)=f(x'xv)$ which differs from $f^{xx'}(v)=f(xx'v)$ by action ordering. I would say $U_{xx'}=U_{x'}\circ U_x$.(i.e. This becomes a right action on the ring of functions.)

My guess is either that $f^x(v)=f(x^{-1}v)$ instead or it should become right action.

Ref. Fogarty, Invariant Theory Chpt 2, Statement right before Definition 2.11

Comment: You are right. The pullback is contravariant $(gh)^\ast = h^\ast g^\ast$ hence it defines an anti-homomorphism (as any right action). taking the pullback by the inverse leads to a left action hence an homomorphism.

Comment: @AlanMuniz that looks like an answer to me! Would you care to record it below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turning the comment into an answer.

Yes you are right in the observation. The action $f^g= g^\ast f$ is just a pullback which is contravariant $(gh)^\ast f = h^\ast g^\ast f$ hence it defines an anti-homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Aut}(k[V])$. Note that this happens for every right action.

Changing to $g\cdot f = f^{g^-1}$ gives a left action 
$$
\left((gh)^{-1}\right)^\ast = \left(h^{-1}g^{-1}\right)^\ast = \left(g^{-1}\right)^\ast\left(h^{-1}\right)^\ast
$$
hence a homomorphism.